# Mycroft on Desktop. How?

Tags: unity, 16.04, snap, mycroft

After [seeing the news of Mycroft running on my favourite distro](http://us3.campaign-archive1.com/?u=56dac47c206ba0f58ec25f314&id=a5b648b4a3&e=c8baf07f63) spreading [over](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=utQjDBM6rF0) and [over](https://plus.google.com/+CarlaSella/posts/XaZyY5HLkv3) and after [seeing it in action on a Desktop system](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DQveAaR7JnI), I decided that I want it.

I tried to look for it with `snap find`, but it is not there

```
[...]
mongo33                    3.3.9                      niemeyer              -        MongoDB document-oriented database
morse-converter-py         1-3                        brunonova             -        Simple command-line Morse converter
mup-accounts               2016.07.01                 niemeyer              -        mup IRC and Telegram bot - account connection side
mup-plugins                2016.07.05                 niemeyer              -        mup IRC and Telegram bot - plugins side
nethack                    3.4.2-2                    ogra                  -        The popular nethack console adventure
nextcloud                  9.0.50snap3                canonical             -        Nextcloud Server
[...]
```

So... Where do I find it and how do I install it? :)

Comment: Indeed, it doesn't seem to be in the Ubuntu store. This may be a question for the Mycroft folks. It's possible that the snaps are still in development.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm really excited that you are interested in Mycroft, and as part of the team I'd like to extend the invitation to you and everyone else here to join our main communication channels (it makes it a little bit easier to collaborate.)

- Community forums: https://community.mycroft.ai
- Slack invite: https://mycroft-ai-slack-invite.herokuapp.com/
- IRC: Server: https://freenode.net, Channel: `#mycroft`

You can download our source code, add issues, discuss futures, and contribute if you like at [our Github repo](https://github.com/MycroftAI/mycroft-core).

Some useful documentation on setting up your development environment and also creating skills can be found here:

- https://docs.mycroft.ai/development
- https://adapt.mycroft.ai/

Finally, to address the fact that Mycroft isn't yet in the snap store, that is correct. I am however working on it here:
https://github.com/MycroftAI/snapcraft-mycroft-core

As soon as I can get it working to an acceptable level I will be uploading it to launchpad.

Also, this `snapcraft.yaml` depends on some modifications I've made to `mycroft-core`, which can be found in [this branch](https://github.com/MycroftAI/mycroft-core/tree/feature/snapcraft).

At this point, core functionality only works in devmode, which means no confinement. Also, I'm having an issue with pocketsphinx, which mean that only the cli client works out of the box. I would absolutely love any help or feedback that you could give me!

If you would prefer to `apt-get install mycroft-core`, I have the solution for that as well.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for answering :) ASAP I'll go through your instruction and trying to set up everything. If you have some time to spare and want to also share how to setup the `apt-get` part I think that this might be very useful for the community :)

Comment: Still not available as a snap and the linked repo hasn't been updated for 10 months. I don't think mycroft is all that serious about the desktop. It sure worked as a marketing thing though because lots of people have watched the mycroft desktop videos.

Comment: I'm afraid the snap package development is pretty stale, and there is much more to do. We are working on a launchpad repository as well.
The desktop is alive and well! There is a KDE plasmoid as well as a really nice gnome shell that are both fairly far along.

Answer (score 0):

Easy Install in Ubuntu & Debian from https://docs.mycroft.ai/installing.and.running/installation/apt-get.install

```
sudo apt-get install apt-transport-https
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys F3B1AA8B
sudo bash -c 'echo "deb http://repo.mycroft.ai/repos/apt/debian debian main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/repo.mycroft.ai.list'
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mycroft-core
```

The following are installed:

```
mycroft-messagebus
mycroft-skills
mycroft-speech-client
```

Start & Stop like:

```
service mycroft-messagebus start
service mycroft-messagebus stop
```

Comment: that link is dead

Answer (score 0):

Installing and running mycroft on ubuntu desktop is possible, however limited and without full skills compatibility due to python issues. Specifically relating to different versions of python and urllib, which is a hurdle in getting various skills dependant upon that to work.

All is not lost however due to https://git.covolunablu.org/portaloffreedom/mycroft-core-PKGBUILD which is a effort to resolve such issues. Anyone who can figure out how to apply it and build using it could have a patched mycroft running on a debian/ubuntu desktop.

Having yet to figure it out myself, still remain hopeful of seeing a good native ubuntu package fully patched and with working skills. Mostly the python issues could be potentially handled or resolved by a seperate tool for debian/ubuntu systems to process and correct various projects porting them to work, perhaps part of the autoconf tools or something similar.

In trying to manually install and build mycroft on my desktop the installation will and has become corrupted and even fails to properly work at times, requiring a full wipe and reinstall of it, including the various skills and config folders. Not something simple and easy for everyone, perhaps ubuntu has spoiled many of us in recent years. Feels like this should however have more created for testing and using it on ubuntu systems.

Still when it works and the skills that are compatible so far seem to work well enough, it is a rather impressive project worth further investments, of time, money and such.